# Gradient color in Vscode active Activity Bar selection border?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Anyone please help me to recreate this look in VSCode. I would like to know how to set the border gradient color of active selection in Activity Bar !

[The look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb1s5.png)

Edit 1: I found out that the theme is Evondev - Dracula but the author only use normal corlor setting for the Activity Bar. He actually has a tutorial for setting the gradient colors for 4 corners of the Active Tab but I can't figure out about the Activity Bar. Here is the link to the tutorial (just scroll down a bit and you can see:

https://evondev.com/code-tuy-bien-cho-vscode/

```
:root{
--size: 5px;
}
.monaco-workbench
  .part.editor
  > .content
  .editor-group-container
  > .title
  .tabs-container
  > .tab.active.tab-border-top
  > .tab-border-top-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.monaco-workbench
  .part.editor
  > .content
  .editor-group-container
  > .title
  .tabs-container
  > .tab.active.tab-border-top
  > .tab-border-top-container:before,
.monaco-workbench
  .part.editor
  > .content
  .editor-group-container
  > .title
  .tabs-container
  > .tab.active.tab-border-top
  > .tab-border-top-container:after {
  content: "";
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
.monaco-workbench
  .part.editor
  > .content
  .editor-group-container
  > .title
  .tabs-container
  > .tab.active.tab-border-top
  > .tab-border-top-container:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(-45deg, #4dd78a, #20e3b2);
}
.monaco-workbench
  .part.editor
  > .content
  .editor-group-container
  > .title
  .tabs-container
  > .tab.active.tab-border-top
  > .tab-border-top-container:after {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(-45deg, #6a5af9, #d66efd);
}
.monaco-workbench
  .part.editor
  > .content
  .editor-group-container
  > .title
  .tabs-container
  > .tab.active:before,
.monaco-workbench
  .part.editor
  > .content
  .editor-group-container
  > .title
  .tabs-container
  > .tab.active:after {
  content: "";
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
.monaco-workbench
  .part.editor
  > .content
  .editor-group-container
  > .title
  .tabs-container
  > .tab.active:before {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(-45deg, #fc6c8f, #ffb86c);
}
.monaco-workbench
  .part.editor
  > .content
  .editor-group-container
  > .title
  .tabs-container
  > .tab.active:after {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(-45deg, #098dff, #2cccff);
}
```

Comment: what is the theme you use, look at the files of the theme how they specify it

Comment: I've tried to looked into the .json file of the theme but he only set the default look.

Comment: evondev is the programmer, it has a theme Dracula but that has no gradients out of the box. He injects custom CSS to replace the styles defined based on the current theme, with the Dev Tools find the CSS selector for the current-bar and write a background gradient in the custom CSS

Comment: the piece of "CSS" you posted needs to be transpiled to CSS, he does not mention the tool to use, it is SCCS?

Comment: whatch the video to see which extension you need to use `Custom CSS` and `Fix VSCode Checksums`

Comment: the source code is plain CSS only the layout confused me

Comment: He used "Custom CSS and JS Loader" Extension. I did try to use Dev Tool but can't find the selector. Could you help me to find it ?

Comment: use the button in the top left of the Dev Tools (square with arrow), then click on the item you want to locate

Answer (score 0):

Found the code with the help of rioV8. Thank you sir !

```
.monaco-workbench
  .activitybar
  > .content
  :not(.monaco-menu)
  > .monaco-action-bar
  .action-item.checked
  .active-item-indicator:before {
  border: 0;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -45deg,  
  #6a5af9, 
  #ff2ced, 
  #fc6c8f,
  #ffb86c);
} 
.monaco-workbench
  .activitybar
  > .content
  :not(.monaco-menu)
  > .monaco-action-bar
  .badge
  .badge-content {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
  #6a5af9, 
  #ff2ced, 
  #fc6c8f,
  #ffb86c);
} 
.monaco-editor .cursors-layer .cursor {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to top,
    -45deg,
  #6a5af9, 
  #ff2ced, 
  #fc6c8f,
  #ffb86c);
}
```